# $_GET Parameter already exist, replace parameter

Tags: wordpress, foreach, parameters, get

I have a question im busy with a filter inside of wordpress. Now i have problem i try to explain.

If a visitor select a "single merk" url gonna be ?merk=Brand1 and than option 2 is select "Soort" than the url is gonna be "?merk=Brand1&soort=Soort1" that works.

But if you have select both, than want to change only ?merk=Brand2 than the url is "?merk=Brand2&soort=Soort1&merk=brand1" how can i make it if you switch between the "merk" that "Brand1" replaced to "Brand2".

Here is the code:

```
            foreach ( $allemerken as $merksingle ) { ?>
                <?php if(isset($_GET['merk']) && $_GET['merk'] == $merksingle->slug){?>
                <a href="<?php echo $current_url; ?>" class="filter_merklink active"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $merksingle->name; ?></a>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $current_url; ?>?merk=<?php echo $merksingle->slug;?><?php if(isset($_GET['soort']) && $_GET['soort'] != ''){ echo '&'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];} ?>" class="filter_merklink"><?php echo $merksingle->name; ?></a>
                <?php }?>
            <?php }?>
            <p class="mt-30"><strong>Soort:</strong></p>
            <?php
            $soorten = get_terms('warmtepompcategorie');           
//            echo '<pre>'.print_r($allemerken,true).'</pre>';
            foreach ( $soorten as $soort ) { ?>
                <?php if(isset($_GET['soort']) && $_GET['soort'] == $soort->slug){?>
                <a href="<?php echo $current_url; ?>" class="filter_merklink active"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $soort->name; ?></a>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $current_url; ?>?soort=<?php echo $soort->slug;?><?php if(isset($_GET['merk']) && $_GET['merk'] != ''){ echo '&'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];} ?>" class="filter_merklink"><?php echo $soort->name; ?></a>
                <?php }?>
            <?php }?>
```

Ps. sorry for my bad English, but hope someone can help me out!

Answer (score 1):

I have made a function.
And i did it like this:

```
function replace_get($newname,$newvalue){
    $oldvars = $_GET;
    $varsnew = $newname.'='.$newvalue;
    foreach($oldvars as $name=> $value){
        if($name != $newname){
            $varsnew .= '&'.$name.'='.$value;
        }
    }
    return $varsnew;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the values from duplicating I would operate on a `$_GET` array, or its copy for adding or removing the parameters like:

```
$_GET['soort'] = 'new value'; // adding, modifying value
unset($_GET['soort']); // removing value
```

and then using [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for building the URL-encoded query string like this:

```
$query = http_build_query(array('aParam' => $data));
```